# DEFERRABLE is unrecognized in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, visual-studio-2022

I created a WPF project in VS 2022 with a service-based database, in ado.net
I created a few tables and when I try to add a constraint in ALTER TABLE and use :
...
ON DELETE SET NULL deferrable initially deferred;
(which worked for me in plsql)

It fails and seems to not recognize the word 'deferrable'.
How can I add this constraint?

Comment: SQL Server does not have deferred constraint checking.

Comment: I suspect there are many things that will work in Oracle and not SQL Server.   (and visa-versa)

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server does not have deferred constraint checking.